# php ajax request gives an error sometimes

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm having some problems trying to figure out what's happening with this ajax request. Sometimes works fine. Sometimes it throws an error.

the ajax function

```
function recoverPass() {
 const loader = $('.loader');
 const data = $('#do-recover').serialize();
 const msg = $('.alert');
 const url = '/ajax/password-recovery';
 const form = $('#do-recover');

 loader.css('display', 'block');

 $('input').removeClass('error');

 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: url,
    cache: false,
 })
 .done(function(response) {
    loader.css('display', 'none');

    msg.removeClass('alert-danger');
    msg.removeClass('alert-warning');
    msg.removeClass('alert-success');

    let json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    let rMsg = json.msg;

    $.each(json['fields'], function(k, v) {
        var id = '#'+v;
        $(id).addClass('error');
    });

    if(json.type === 'error') {
        msg.addClass('alert-danger');
    }
    else if(json.type === 'success') {
        msg.addClass('alert-success');

        form[0].reset();
    }
    else {
        msg.addClass('alert-danger');
        rMsg = '<strong>Ups, something went wrong!</strong>';
    }

    msg.html(rMsg);
    console.log(json);
 })
 .fail(function() {
    loader.css('display', 'none');

    msg.addClass('alert-danger');
    msg.html('<strong>Ups, something went wrong!</strong>');
 })
 return false;
}
```

in my php file i have this:

```
$response = [
    'error' => $error,
    'fields' => $fields,
    'msg' => $msg,
    'type' => $type
];
// send the array in json format
echo json_encode($response);
```

and the JSON resulting is the following:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "fields": [],
  "msg": "Please check your email!",
  "type": "success"
}
```

this is an email script. I'm using PHPMailer. The email is always sent, but sometimes I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

other times the system works perfectly.

Oh, and I did try to add **`dataType: json`**.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

this is all the error message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
recoverPass http://www.blogish.local/js/functions.js:158
jQuery 6
    c
    fireWith
    l
    o
    send
    ajax
recoverPass http://www.blogish.local/js/functions.js:145
onclick http://www.blogish.local/password-recovery:1
```

Comment: When you get the error, what is the content of the response body?  (Also, does the error *really* say "other times the system works perfectly"?  Does the error perhaps indicate what the character is?)

Comment: tks for poiting that. its already edited. all the error message is posted and as far as the json response, i get noting when i get the error (if that's the response body you're asking).

Comment: Normally this is happening it the backend is giving errors or warnings before the return of the JSON. If you take a look at the browsers development tools and take at the RAW response of the request you will find it

Comment: tks @Claus. After looking at what you pointed, i think i figured out what was happening. still need to run some more tests but i after some tries the error didnt happened anymore.